# How to get smoother values?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

I am working on a project and one of the parts is to generate a mountain. Someone passed me the source code and I've tried to modify it to fit my needs but the output is not exactly what it needs to be.

It is great to generate some flat values for an island maybe, but not so great at generating smooth height values for a mountain.

At first, it seems to look good because it generates a nice shape but you can see the abrupt changes from color to color. When I pass the texture to a 3D Terrain, this is what it looks like:
[image]

Anyways, the 3D Mountain should not look like this even though the base shape is fine. I am looking for something similar to this height values, it's much smoother:
[image]

After analyzing the source code for a while I reckon that the problem seems to be that the values are truncated. I think the problem is in the Noise() function above, especially with the Pow functions, but I'm not sure.
I would be very glad if someone can contribute towards fixing this. Thank you and have a Great Day!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the Noise function because it returned an int, which truncated all the values as a result.